# Google Chrome App while running on android emulator giving error

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

I'm trying to run a simple `Hello` chrome app on android emulator. After navigating to the app directory when I run

```
cca emulate android
```

After some time I get an error:

Here is the full cmd line response:

```
cca v0.4.1
Running command: /home/jay/HelloChromeAppOnAndroid/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to myAvd
Waiting for emulator...
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Booting up emulator (this may take a while).......................BOOT COMPLETE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jay/HelloChromeAppOnAndroid/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 175

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No match found

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.074 secs

/home/jay/HelloChromeAppOnAndroid/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /home/jay/HelloChromeAppOnAndroid/platforms/android/gradlew with args: assembleArmv7Debug,-b,/home/jay/HelloChromeAppOnAndroid/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-x,lint,-x,lintVitalX86Release,-x,lintVitalArmv7Release,-x,compileLint,-x,copyReleaseLint,-x,copyDebugLint
Error: /home/jay/HelloChromeAppOnAndroid/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/jay/.nvm/v0.10.32/lib/node_modules/cca/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem's like the problem has been fixed. I had posted an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/374) and it's resolved now.

All you got to do is

```
npm install -g cca
```

to update the toolchain.